# parse a csv file in C#

Tags: c#

```
String[] values = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/state.csv").Split(',');
Console.WriteLine(values);
Console.ReadLine();
```

it just prints out: System.String[] onto console and the program is
running for a long time

Comment: FYI: CSV formatting is more complex than simply splitting the lines based on commas. For example, what if a row contained this data: `10, Street Name,"Smith, John",Postcode` ?

Comment: it contains just 0's and 1's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think iterating through the items is a good idea if you just have split it before. I would change your code like that:

```
string valuesString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/state.csv");
Console.WriteLine(valuesString);
String[] values = valuesString.Split(',');
```

This way you will split this string only once. If you want to extend the buffer of the console, you should do

```
Console.BufferHeight = Int16.MaxValue - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this seems to work , although i can view only the last few lines of CSV file on the console. is there any other way to display all the contents instead of the following: foreach(var v in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Are you asking if you can somehow extend what is displayed on the console? Meaning the buffer? I edited the response.

Comment: Do i need to close the csv file after its opened

Comment: You don't need to close the file. ReadAllText opens, reads and closes the file after its done.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `ToString()` method of a (non-string) type is overriden, it will just return the name of the type of the object, in this case; "System.String[]".

You want to print all the values in the array.Try this:

```
String[] values = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/state.csv").Split(',');

foreach( var v in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , it seems to work although just prints out only the last few lines of data

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the loop to print

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/Users/state.csv");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
   string[] values = line.Split(',');
   foreach(var item in values)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(item);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input , but it displays only last few lines of the file

Comment: ok got it what you are searching, wait for a minute I am updating my answer

Comment: see my update it will read your csv as line by line and after that it splite all line by comma  then you can iterate over that data and can get seperate data point

Comment: Thanks for the update, i got an error stating cannot convert string[] to string so i changed it to : string[] values = line.Split(','); and now , it just prints out the headers in the csv file

Comment: ok it was sily mistake, if your csv is correct then you should get all the value with your header I have just tested

Comment: Thanks a lot , csv files seems to be correct and only last 500 rows are displayed ? in total i have 700 rows any thoughts

Comment: from normal thought if 500 line print then other 200 should also print if they are ok, check your csv again is there any extra character present or not

Comment: Do i need to close the CSV file ,could that be a problem? Thanks

Comment: no need to close your csv here, because you are not using stream reader

Answer (score 0):

`.ToString()` method on an array will return "System.String[]". use loop and print each item if you need to print each item in the array.

or use string join like below

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values));
```